# A windows service application controlled by desktop application?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I created a windows service in C# where I can start , stop, restart.

Is there anyway of creating a simple desktop application to control it.

example: button to start service
button to stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at [this article](http://www.csharp-examples.net/restart-windows-service/). It explains how to stop/start/restart a service in a nice manner.

All you then need to do is create a new WinForms/WPF Application, add 3 buttons (style as you like) and assign those methods to the click events of the buttons.

Easy as pie, let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a windows application and can add that exe to the schedule task (in control panel). There you can schedule the time. Also you can manually start and stop there